# submit button not working in spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My submit button does not hit the controller when I click on it in my spring mvc application

```
<div class="form-group">    
                          <form action="searchInfo" method="GET">
                              <label class=" control-label col-sm-2">No</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-4"> <input class="form-control" type='text' name='searchName' id='searchName'/> </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-4"><input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' value='Validate'/></div>
                          </form>
                         </div>
```

this is the controller code

```
@Autowired
    private IndividualService infoService;

    @RequestMapping("getAllInfo")
    public ModelAndView getAllInfo() {
        return new ModelAndView("sDescription");
    }

    @RequestMapping("searchInfo")
    public ModelAndView searchInfo(@RequestParam("searchName") String searchName) {  
        logger.info("Searching the Individual Info: "+searchName);
        List<InfoIndividual> infoList = infoService.getAllInfos(searchName);
        return new ModelAndView("sDescription", "infoList", infoList);      
    }
```

this is the web.xml code for the app descriptor definition

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>emInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>emInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/Error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/Error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Please why is my spring application not hitting the controller when I click the subit button of my form. Has debugged every layer and it still looks thesame

Comment: What error do you see when you click that submit button?

Comment: I do not see any error. The page just refreshes

Comment: Did you see white screen after you press validate? Did you the logger in your console? Please share what is there in sDescription.

Comment: @VijendraKulhade the page just refreshes and nothing else

Comment: @AndreaRobinson I took your code and try to run it. I am getting the request in controller. may be your spring container itself is not initialized properly.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because of the value attr on the submit button and you have no matching controller method. Try getting rid of it.
Change

```
 <div class="col-sm-4"><input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' **value='Validate'**/></div>
```

to

```
 <div class="col-sm-4"><input class="btn btn-success" type='submit'/></div>
```